# Best approach for high-read table where query depends on computed values

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I have the following table:

```
        StartDate - datetimeoffset(0);
    EventDuration - time(0);
RecurrenceEndDate - datetimeoffset(0);
```

99% of the queries on this table will require the computation `RecurrenceEndDate + EventDuration`.

This particular query to select only relevant records for a certain analysis will be run very, very often:

```
SELECT * FROM RRules WHERE

**RecurrenceEndDate + EventDuration** >= START_DATE --Make sure last recurrent event did/will not end before START_DATE, which would make the rule irrelevant for the analysis.

AND StartDate < END_DATE' --Make sure the first occurrence of the event is before END_DATE;
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario where the same computation is required virtually every query? I feel like storing the computation value on a column is wrong since it can be computed.

Comment: Pinal Dave goes into depth on computed columns, and it isn't black & white as to whether persisted columns are faster. If the computation is complex then persisted should be faster, otherwise non-persisted can be faster. Here's the link https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/07/27/sql-server-computed-column-persisted-and-storage/

Comment: yes persisted columns is one option. May be your tables are already very heavy .second option is to create inline UDF.like you said there are lot of calculation, so may be both option.May be your table structure is wrong.May be the way you are populating table is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you create a [computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188300.aspx):

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for the column to which it belongs.

For example, this will create the column non-persisted which means the calculation happens every time you use the column:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ChooseABetterName AS (RecurrenceEndDate + EventDuration)
```

Or as a persisted column which is stored along side your data and doesn't have to be calculated every time:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ChooseABetterName AS (RecurrenceEndDate + EventDuration) PERSISTED
```

Now you can use the computed column directly:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE ChooseABetterName >= START_DATE
```

It is also possible to [create indexes on computed columns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: but won't this still peform the computation everytime? Or is the computed column value cached?

Comment: Yes it will calculate every time, but you can make the column PERSISTED which stores the value (and updates it as required)

Comment: Though you can create an index (added a link in answer)

Comment: A persisted computed column would be the same as a regular column which holds the value, except I would have to populated it upon insertion right? Guess that persisted computed will have to do. I want to avoid indexes since this is a datetimeoffset column, and the overhead can be a problem

Comment: I came across this answer stackoverflow.com/a/30678751/1836773 where the suggestion is that to use an index on a datetime column, one should have a special separate column holding a "normalized" version of the date to save space because the index overhead would be quite problematic for a field that is too specific/unique. What do you think

Comment: @victor I'm not entirely convinced by that answer. However, every situation is different and the only way you are going to know which method is best for you is to prototype it and try it out. But... as with anything to do with performance you need to ask yourself "how fast is fast enough?" I highly recommend reading Eric Lippert's excellent blog post on the subject https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 0):

> but won't this still peform the computation every time?

Yes, it will.  And @DavidG is providing the [right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42103136/451601). Yes, you can persist a computed column, but it's far from obvious that will result in better performance.

In a database, performance comes from minimizing I/O.  I/O costs thousands of times what computation does.  Almost anything you do to replace I/O with computation is a win.

For example, when computers were still young and wild poodles roamed the earth, we kept lists of random numbers in our database, the better to produce reproducible stochastic results.  Later, we replaced those tables with the algorithm that produced them, because it was faster to re-compute the same numbers over and over again than it was just to read them off the disk.

Computed columns save you the cost of computing numbers that will never be read, the time to write them, and the time to maintain that logic.

Finally, remember: *There are only two hard things in computer science: cache coherency, and naming things*.  Your pre-computed values are a cache, and introduce the problem of making sure they're consistent with the underlying values.  Not hard?  OK.  But why bother until you know it's necessary?

Comment: DB engine will take care of the computed column values, OP won't have to compute these manually per se :-)) Btw, it's the cache *invalidation* (timing) that is hard, not the precomputation and retrieving part as in this case.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that without the computed column, the DB engine has to read both `RecurrenceEndDate` and `EventDuration` columns to determine the result of the query clause. Include an index on the computed column and it can even potentially skip a bunch of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Create a persisted computed column over the whole expression:

```
alter table RRules 
add column IsRelevant as (cast(case when StartDate + EventDuration >= StartDate then 1 else 0 end as bit)) persisted
```

Use this column as part of other relevant indexes, not by itself (because of low selectivity). You can even add it to the WHERE clause of a filtered index.

Comment: START_DATE is not the same as StarDate, it is variable.

Comment: Sry, you got me cofused listing the startdate among the table's columns. Also, variables are prefixed with @ in T-SQL.